# Apache + LDAP Auth: access to / failed, reason: require directives present and no Authoritative handler

Tags: debian, apache-2.2, ldap

Can't solve this one, here's my .htaccess:

```
AuthPAM_Enabled Off

AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
AuthName "MESSAGE"
Require ldap-group cn=CHANGED, cn=CHANGED

AuthLDAPURL "ldap://localhost/dc=CHANGED,dc=CHANGED?uid?sub?(objectClass=posixAccount)"
AuthLDAPBindDN CHANGED
AuthLDAPBindPassword CHANGED
AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
```

AuthLDAPURL is correct, BindDN and BindPassword are correct also (verified with ldapvi -D ..).

Apache version: Apache/2.2.9 (Debian)

The error message seems cryptic to me, I have AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on so where's the problem.

EDIT:

LDAP modules are loaded, the problem is not with them being missing.

```
# ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*ldap*
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authnz_ldap.load  /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ldap.load
```

EDIT2:

Solved it by changing funky

```
Require ldap-group cn=CHANGED, cn=CHANGED
```

line with

```
Require valid-user
```

Since AuthzLDAPAuthoritative is on, no other auth methods will be used and valid-user requirement will auth via LDAP. (right? :/)

Comment: Do you have two "cn"s in your Require ldap-group, or is just your redacting?

Comment: Funny question, but you did do AllowOverride all in your <Directory "/"> definition, right?

Comment: Was my comment enough that I should post it as an answer and you accept it? :)

Comment: Sure, go ahead :)

Comment: What LDAP source are you using? I have found that the Windows AD LDAP implementation does not allow for a 'sub' level search on a DC, but does work on an OU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'Require' line reads

> Require ldap-group cn=CHANGED, cn=CHANGED

That doesn't look write - I don't believe you can have have two cn's in a DN like that.

Comment: One note on Require ldap-group If you are connecting to the global catalog port, keep in mind that group memberships are NOT replicated to global catalogs UNLESS the group is a universal group. I.e. if you make a Global group AND try to authenticate using require ldap-group AND are connecting to port 3268 IT WILL NOT WORK. Convert it to a universal group and viola.

Answer (score 1):

For me and apache 2.2.14, this works like a champ for access control on a per-group basis

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Secret Area for IT Only"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap1.example.int ldap2.company.int/cn=int"
Require ldap-group cn=it,ou=Groups,o=int
```

"int" is our internal domain for non-public servers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the **ldap** and **authnz_ldap** modules?

You can do so with:

```
a2enmod ldap authnz_ldap; /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Yes, I have them loaded. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: "No authoritative handler" implies that apache cannot use them for some reason.